# Grep for a special pattern

Tags: linux, grep

I am looking for a pattern like the one below-

```
.mm1(moda.portb)
.mab(blah.pc)
```

I am trying this-

```
grep -ir ".(*.*)"  .
```

Unfortunately, with this expression, i get a lot of results like-
.mm1(moda)
.mab(blah)

How do I change my pattern so i can grep all files in my directory with an expression that is - `.characters(characters.characters)`

Help is appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not currently on a unix environment so sorry for not testing, but it seems to me like you wanna escape your periods:

```
grep -ir "\.(*\.*)"  .
```

Comment: thanks, it works, is possible to remove all commented lines (lines beginning with or including \\ in this grep? )

Comment: You need to pipeline it.  `grep -ir "\.(*\.*)" | grep -v '//'`, where the `grep -v` means "find all lines that do not match the expression."

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the special characters.

```
grep -ir ".*.\(.*\..*\)" .
```